# Disable jquery script if width is below 480

Tags: javascript

```js
function init() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
            var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                shrinkOn = 0,
                header = document.querySelector("header");
            if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
                classie.add(header,"smaller");
            } else {
                if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                    classie.remove(header,"smaller");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    window.onload = init();
```

```css
body {margin-bottom:2000px;}
header {
  height:80px;
  position:fixed;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -ms-transition:  all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
  background:grey;
  width:100%;
  }

header.smaller {
  height:30px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -ms-transition:  all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
  }
```

```html
<script src="http://callmenick.com/_development/resize-header-on-scroll/js/classie.js"></script>

<body>
<header>
  header
</header>
</body>
```

Hello im using a jquery shinking header plugin and it works perfect. Just dont want to use this effect on browsers below an width of 480px. Is there a way to disable the plugin on browsers below 480px?

Help would be highly appreciated, 
Best regards!

Comment: No jQuery appears at Question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATED.

Since you are not using jQuery, check the code below with plain Javascript.

---

Replace your code  with the code below:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    
  if(window.innerWidth > 480) { 

  // your code will only run if width of window is over 480px
    
    // === START OF YOUR CODE ===

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 0,
            header = document.querySelector("header");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            classie.add(header,"smaller");
        } else {
            if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                classie.remove(header,"smaller");
            }
        }
    });
    
    // === END OF YOUR CODE ===
  }
};

window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
// triggers resize event so user doesn't have to only resize to trigger your code
```

Comment: Did not manage to make it work. Might be doing something wrong. Im not much of a coder. Could you be more specific what i need to change? Best regards!

Comment: Check it out now, I've replaced the whole answer with plain Javascript instead of using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can check `window.innerWidth` or `screen.width` at `load` event of `window`

```
window.onload = function() {
  if ((this.innerWidth || screen.width)  > 480) init()
}
```

Comment: I really dont know much about javascript coding. Could you be more specific how i use this please? Best regards!

Comment: @Jeppa Use same pattern at Question. Use `load` event handler to check if `window.innerWidth` or `screen.width` is greater than `480`, if true, call `init()` function